# Unable to Unvote to Open?

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-reopen

I recently asked a question that was closed due to being a duplicate.  I didn't notice the link to the original question at first, so I knee-jerk voted to reopen it.

After finding the link, I realized that I couldn't remove the vote to reopen the question.  Shouldn't clicking the "Reopen" again remove your vote to reopen the question?

Comment: On MSE: [Ability to retract reopen/delete votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193061/ability-to-retract-reopen-delete-votes)

Comment: While someone may erroneously vote to reopen every once in a while, but keep in mind the post needs to collect 5 of them to actually get reopened.  I just don't see that happening often enough (if at all) to actually warrant needing this functionality.

Comment: @Servy I imagine it goes into the Reopen queue, which is why I wanted to retract my vote.

Comment: @Dropped.on.Caprica And if people sincerely think it should be reopened, they'll vote to reopen it, and if it shouldn't be, then it'll get a few "stay closed" votes and that will be that.

Comment: @Servy True, true.

Comment: FWIW these fly through the Reopen Votes queues fairly quickly since that queue is usually empty. If it is left closed, the vote will automatically expire in 4 days, assuming no further reopen votes accumulate after that.

Comment: @animuson Yeah, true.  I did notice that queue was tiny compared to the Close queue, so I'm assuming it is similar to the Late Answers / First Posts queue.